# How to show html tags in a sylk file in excel

Tags: html, excel

We are making sylk files from an application when you export to excel.
This is working fine when no html tags are inside.

For example when I get the following sylk file:

```
ID;PWFORMS
P;Pdd-mm-yyyy\ hh:mm
C;Y1;X1;K"Description"
C;Y2;X1;K"These are html tags: <html><body><pre>...</pre></body></html> that are not showing correctly"
E
```

If I want to open it in excel it gives me errors and it won't open correctly.
I know I can put underscores instead of the "<" sign. But I like to show the correct html code, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: The file format and extension of 'test.slk' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?